# Keep saved data in form after revisiting the page

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a form with three input fields. I managed to find out how to keep the data after saving the form, but when I leave the page and come back to this form, the fields are empty again.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

                        if(isset($_POST['save_home_details'])) {

                            $home_title     = escape_string($_POST['home_title']);
                            $home_desc      = escape_string($_POST['home_desc']);
                            $home_keywords  = escape_string($_POST['home_keywords']);

                            $query = "INSERT INTO settings(home_title, home_desc, home_keywords) ";
                            $query .= "VALUES('{$home_title}', '{$home_desc}', '{$home_keywords}') ";

                            $home_details_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                            confirm($home_details_query);

                            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Settings saved successfully!</div>";

                        }

                    ?>

                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="home_title">Home title</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="home_title" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['home_title'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['home_title']); }?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="home_title">Home description</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="home_desc" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['home_desc'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['home_desc']); }?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="home_title">Home keywords</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="home_keywords" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['home_keywords'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['home_keywords']); }?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="save_home_details" value="Save settings">
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

Basically what I want here is:

- to be able to add value to these fields
- save the values
- keep the values in the fields whenever I come back to this page
- if I click the save settings button, update the values and not add a new record to the database.

I know I haven't added the update query yet, but can I do that on the same page where I insert the values into the database?

Thanks

Comment: Use `Select` query to get data from DB don't use `$_POST` and show data from selected query result.

Comment: I'm getting an undefined variable error if I do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store temporarily you can use $_SESSION['anyData'] = $anyData.
When you do not need you can unset($_SESSION['anyData'])